# Webpack Angular2 cannot find .ts files from widget library

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to integrate a component library in an angular2/webpack/typescript project.

The library is already transpiled to javascript, however when it is loaded, it looks like webpack is looking for the .ts files instead.
Here is the webpack configuration I am using:

```
module.exports = {
  ......
  entry: {

    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'main': './src/main.ts'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  .....
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
        {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'source-map-loader', exclude: [helpers.root('node_modules/rxjs')]}
    ],
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader', exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]} ,
      {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'},
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'raw-loader'},
      {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader', exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]}
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new ForkCheckerPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({name: ['main', 'vendor', 'polyfills'], minChunks: Infinity}),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets'}]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: 'src/index.html', chunksSortMode: 'none'}),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV), 'HMR': HMR})
  ]  
};
```

I am running the application in the webpack dev server.
Here is the error message:

```
./~/primeng/components/selectbutton/selectbutton.js
Cannot find source file 'selectbutton.ts': Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./selectbutton.ts in C:\data\14-03\angular2-webpack-starter\node_modules\primeng\components\selectbutton
```

Comment: @BobSponge Yes, looks like that is the case

Comment: Try to change `devtool` to `hidden-source-map`: `devtool: "hidden-source-map"`

Comment: @BobSponge nope, the issue remains.

Comment: Okay, next try. Disable source-map generation for ts-files in tsconfig: `"sourceMap": false` and `"inlineSourceMap": false` in compiler options ( https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader#tsconfigjson )

Comment: @BobSponge same...

Comment: But if you excluding `node_modules` at all  (not just `rxjs`) from `source-map-loader` it works?

Comment: @BobSponge Yes, it does. Guess will have to live with that...

Comment: As of PrimeNG 0.8, the ts files are included.

Comment: While primeng is providing .ts files now which is great, the original question still baffles me as well...

Comment: There is a PrimeNG+WebPack sample here. https://github.com/primefaces/primeng-quickstart-webpack

Answer (score 11):

I was able to solve this error by updating the webpack config to exclude sourcemaps from primeng:

```
module.exports = {
  ....
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      ...
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader',
        exclude: [
          helpers.root('node_modules/primeng')
        ]
      }
    ]
    ...
  }
  ...
};
```

Comment: how to fix in webpack.dev.js file? Mine run in webpack dev enviroment and I dont know where to fix, here is my webpack.dev.js file:  http://pastie.org/10875854

Comment: You shouldn't need to if your `webpack.common.js` file has this since you're using `webpackMerge` to pull in those settings.

Comment: No, it will run in webpack.dev.js. Here is my webpack.config.js, since my  NODE_ENV is dev, it will run my webpack.dev.js http://pastie.org/10877975

Comment: Gotcha, but in your dev file you are merging the configuration values from the common config file.

See line: `module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {...`

Comment: OMG I LOVE YOU SO MUCHHHH, found the file from commonConfig variable, edit and it worked!!!

Comment: if you run into issues with helpers.root - use this instead....path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\primeng"),